# Parallelisation - Why does sleep pause only once?

Tags: parallel-processing, go, goroutine

Why do wait only the first goroutine with

`func Sleep(d Duration)`
http://golang.org/pkg/time
"Sleep pauses the current goroutine for the duration d."

but the rest is execute directly. I think cause the channel `c chan string` but i dont understand the behaviour between both.

[My Example GoPlayground](http://play.golang.org/p/S1y-4YMESY)

Answer (score 4):

All your go routines are running concurrently so they all sleep for 4 seconds at the same time, hence they all end at the same time.

You called them like this.  The `go` means that all the `getHostName` functions run at once.

```
for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
    go getHostName(haveHost, ipadresse_3, i)
}
```

And this means that all the sleeps happen at the same time

```
func getHostName(h chan string, ipAdresse string, n int) {

    //Here!!!
    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
    ip := ipAdresse + strconv.Itoa(n)

    //ip, ok := net.LookupAddr(ip)

    if false {
        h <- ip + " - "
    } else {
        h <- "error" + strconv.Itoa(n)  
    }
}
```

So they all finish at the same time.

Comment: yes you´re rigth but why does the first goRoutine sleep and the rest routines wait for it?

Comment: ok i have understood. it just seems that the goRoutines wait of it but in fact the time is lapsed one time for one concurrency "moment" right?

Comment: Get four people together and tell them to wait four seconds and then say something.  What happens?